# IF statement is being ignored, code recognizes the sum but ignores the IF statement Revised

Tags: python

I have a DataFrame looking like this, I am trying to find the max sum of the iterative (looped) calculation of sum of 4 rows in the Dataframe, I can get the sum but code is ignoring the If statement and gives me the last counter=4, value.
|x |
|--|
| 1|
| 4|
| 1|
| 2|
| 0|
| 0|
| 0|
| 0|
| 0|
| 0|
| 0|

```
maxb=0
count=0

while (count<4):
    
    count=count+1
    curra= (df.iloc[count:count+4].sum())
if curra > maxb:
    maxb=curra

print(maxb)
```

Comment: No it isn't.  But you probably meant `maxb = curra` rather than `==` which tests whether they are equal.

Comment: incidentally, the code doesn't make much sense: `maxb = max(maxb, curra)` would do what you want more idiomatically, and in any case there is no need to assign maxb to itself.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `==` which is a *comparison* operator. This returns a bool and doesn't actually assign anything. What you want is `maxb = curra`. The single `=` is an *assignment* operator.

Comment: * `maxb = curra`.  The `maxb = maxb` line is never going to do anything.

Comment: @2e0byo Ah whoops, edited.

Comment: Hey folks, you great programmers out there, help, I am very new to Python, I have done some research, I found it is do with when "if curra>maxb" is false then the "if statement" jumps over the next line of code, but do not know how to fix it as inevitably at some point the IF statement will be false, what then???? how to handle it.

Comment: This question can be closed, I had the counter "count=count+1" in the wrong location, in the begining, the right location should have been  at the end of my statements.

Comment: @Sanjog for future reference: if you need to loop over a set range you can instead do `for i in range(4):`

Comment: BTables: Thanks for the tip, I'll change the code, and see if it speeds up, actually I am looping over more than 8000 rows in the real code,